# Escaping html characters in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I would like to escape some html characters that I have stored in an array.

```
var quiz = [{
    "question": "How would we use css to select an element with <h1 class = \"intro\">",
    "choices": [".intro{ property: attribute }", "intro{ property :attribute }", "#intro{property: attribute }"],
    "correct": ".intro{ property: attribute }"
}, {
    "question": "How would we select the element with id firstname <p id=\"firstname\">?",
    "choices": ["#firstname{ property: attribute }", ".firstname{ property: attribute }", "who cares?"],
    "correct": "#firstname{ property: attribute }"
}, {
    "question": "How would we select all elements?",
    "choices": ["#{ property: attribute }",  "@all{ property: attribute }", "*{ property: attribute }"],
    "correct": "*{ property: attribute }"
}, {
    "question": "what does this do div > p?",
    "choices": ["Selects all <p> elements inside <div> elements", "Selects <p> element that is a child of <div>", "Selects all <p> that are placed immediately after <div>"],
    "correct": "Selects <p> element that is a child of <div>"
}, {
    "question": "what does div + p do?",
    "choices": ["Selects all <div> and <p> elements", "Selects all <p> elements inside <div> elements", "Selects all <p> elements that are placed immediately after <div> elements"],
    "correct": "Selects all <p> elements that are placed immediately after <div> elements"
}];
```

I know that there are multiple answers to escaping html tags within javascript.  For example I found this function which is very straightforward.

```
var htmlString = "<h1>My HTML STRING</h1><p>It has html characters & such in it.</p>";
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#replaceDiv").text(htmlString)
   });
```

However, all the solutions I have seen require creating a function assigning variables etc.  This seems overly complicated.  Is there any easier way to accomplish my goals here?

Comment: string.js has many useful methods http://stringjs.com/

Comment: what characters are you trying to escape?

Comment: I am trying to escape the html tags

Comment: `$(document).ready` just ensures that your script doesn't try to replace things in the document before it's fully loaded. The `var htmlString = "<h1>My...` is merely an example for the text

Comment: @GrawCube Right, I understand that, but, my point is that I would have to assign a whole bunch of variables for each string that has html tags that need to be escaped.  So suppose this program ends up having a bunch of answers to questions that have tags that need to be escaped.  I would end up having a ton of variables which seems really redundant.

Comment: What? You already have your variable(s) assigned! The array!

Comment: @GrawCube  Eureka!  I can just parse the whole array?

Comment: Er...if you want to? I would escape the strings right before I use them but I don't know what you're using these arrays for so I can't tell you a proper answer to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74119/discussion-between-grawcube-and-michael-james).

Comment: So replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @GrawCube for help in the chat room.

Solution was to create an `escape function` and then parse the `quiz` array.

```
function escapeHtmlChars(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

for (var i = 0; i < quiz.length; i++) {
    quiz[i].correct = escapeHtmlChars(quiz[i].correct);
    for (var j = 0; j < quiz[i].choices.length; j++) {
        quiz[i].choices[j] = escapeHtmlChars(quiz[i].choices[j]);
    }
}
```